# не работает event.preventDefault(); после применения $('#content').load();

Tags: javascript

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#login_form").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event);
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "account/login",
            data: data,
            success: function(res) {
                MessageSend(res[0],res[1],res[2],res[3],res[4]);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

до загрузки страницы методом load() все работает хорошо, после использования события load() пример приведенный выше перестает работать. Не могу понять в чем проблема, помогите пожалуйста

и вот сама метод load();

```
$('#content').load(page + '#load', function(response, status, xhr) {
    history.pushState(null, name, page);
    if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "Просим прощения за следующую ошибку: ";
        $("#content").html(msg + '<b style="color:red;">' + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText + '</b>');
        document.title = 'Ошибка: ' + name;
    } else {
        document.title = name;
    }
    $('html, body').scrollTop(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Если твоя форма подгружается используя load(), то event.preventDefault() не сработает, так как в таком виде обработчики события вешаются при загрузке страницы, и твоей формы в это время еще нет, поэтому обработчик повесить не на что. Тебе надо повесить обработчик на документ и после вызова события, проверять, что это за элемент и, если это твоя форма, тогда дальше уже исполнять нужный код.
Например:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).submit(function(event){
        if($(event.currentTarget).attr('id') !== "login_form"){
            return false;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event);
        var elem = $(event.currentTarget());
        var data = elem .serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "account/login",
            data: data,
            success: function(res) {
                MessageSend(res[0],res[1],res[2],res[3],res[4]);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        el = event.target.id;
        var data = $('#' + el).serialize();
        var pathname = window.location.pathname;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'account' + pathname,
            data: data,
            success: function(res) {
                MessageSend(res[0],res[1],res[2],res[3],res[4]);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

в итоге сделал вот так